# Replace text with text which in entered in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the text field code

```
 <input type="text" name="total" value="<?=$data->Total;?>" placeholder="Net Total" id="input-sku" class="form-control">
```

In which when i enter something it should automatically replace the text "AMOUNT" with entered value of above textfield.

This is code of that textfield:

```
 <textarea name="reciept" rows="8" id="input-comment" class="form-control">Please pay exactly AMOUNT to this account</textarea>
```

So when i enter any value in textfield it should replace the text AMOUNT with it in textarea. I think it will be jquery

Comment: $('#total').val($('#input-comment').val())

Comment: It should replace the text AMOUNT

Comment: How do you call your event? Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure you can use the "template" over and over, I saved it using `data()` (you can [read more here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)).
Besides that - to make sure that no one can change the content of your textarea I set it to `disabled` to make sure the user will not be able to change the value there.

Check this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#input-comment').data('originalContent', $('textarea').val());
  $('input[name=total]').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      newval = $('#input-comment').data('originalContent').replace('AMOUNT', $(this).val())
      $('#input-comment').val(newval);
    } else {
      $('#input-comment').val($('#input-comment').data('originalContent'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="total" value="123" placeholder="Net Total" id="input-sku" class="form-control"><br />
<textarea name="reciept" rows="8" cols="50" id="input-comment" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">Please pay exactly AMOUNT to this account</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for it but as i use: <textarea><?=$data->Reciept;?></textarea> so it does work sometime on half load of the page but when it fully loads and i add text in it then it doesn't works